# Allow duplicate node name in XML serialization using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm trying to serialize an object that have a duplicate node name using C#, the reason what i need to do this is because i'm building a library that use a third party API.

The request i need to build look like this.

```
<DATASET>
   <SITE_ID>123</SITE_ID>
   <DATA type=“name”>Secondary List</DATA>
   <DATA type="extra" id="CLICKTHRU_URL">http://my.domain.com/</DATA>
   <DATA type="extra" id="REPLY_FORWARD_EMAIL">support@my.domain.com</DATA>
   <DATA type="extra" id="REPLY_FROM_EMAIL">forward@my.domain.com</DATA>
   <DATA type="extra" id="REPLY_FROM_NAME">8@yahoo.com</DATA>
   <DATA type="extra" id="REPLY_FORWARD_SUBJECT">Customer Replies</DATA>
   <DATA type="extra" id="HANDLE_UNSUBSCRIBE"></DATA>
   <DATA type="extra" id="HANDLE_AUTOREPLY"></DATA>
   <DATA type="extra" id="FOOTER_TEXT">Confidentiality agreement…</DATA>
   <DATA type="extra" id="FOOTER_HTML"> Confidentiality agreement…</DATA>
</DATASET>
```

My approach is create a class that represent the request and use the XML serialization attributes, the class look like this:

```
[XmlRoot("DataSet")]
public class AddListCallHolder : BaseCallHolder
{
    private BaseAttributeHolder _name = new BaseAttributeHolder(type: "");

    [XmlElement("DATA")]
    public BaseAttributeHolder Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    private BaseAttributeHolder _clickthruUrl = new BaseAttributeHolder(id: "CLICKTHRU_URL");

    [XmlElement("DATA")]
    public BaseAttributeHolder CLICKTHRU_URL
    {
        get { return _clickthruUrl; }
        set { _clickthruUrl = value; }
    }
}
```

The base class of the attribute is:

```
public class BaseAttributeHolder
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public BaseAttributeHolder(string value, string id, string type = "extra")
    {
        Type = type;
        Value = value;
        Id = id;
    }

    public BaseAttributeHolder(string id, string type = "extra")
    {
        Type = type;
        Id = id;
    }

    public BaseAttributeHolder(string type = "extra")
    {
        Type = type;
    }

    public BaseAttributeHolder()
    {

    }
}
```

When i try to serialize and object i getting this error:

> The XML element 'DATA' from namespace '' is already present in the current scope. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element.

Is there any work around to serialize this object or get the the structure of the request.

Comment: +1 for a really well asked first question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using an array or list to de-serialize all `<DATA>`'s and then add properties which operate on this array?

```
  [XmlRoot("DataSet")]
  public class AddListCallHolder
  {
      [XmlArrayItem(typeof(BaseAttributeHolder), ElementName = "DATA")]
      public BaseAttributeHolder[] data 
      { 
           get;
           set;
      }

      [XmlIgnore]
      public BaseAttributeHolder Name
      {
          get
          {
             return data.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Type == "name");
          }
      }

      [XmlIgnore]
      public BaseAttributeHolder CLICKTHRU_URL
      {
          get
          {
             return data.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Type == "extra" && d.Id == "CLICKTHRU_URL");
          }
      }
  }
```

I think you will also be able to come up with the setters.

Comment: Thank you, clean solution.
Thank you all for the quick answer, and the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this without customizing the serialization yourself; the issue is that it the serializer needs to uniquely identify the serialized properties in the output. If they all have the name "DATA" it can't really do this.

What you could do instead is:

```
[XmlType(TypeName="Data")]
public class BaseAttributeHolder
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }


    public BaseAttributeHolder(string value, string id, string type = "extra")
    {
        Type = type;
        Value = value;
        Id = id;
    }

    public BaseAttributeHolder(string id, string type = "extra")
    {
        Type = type;
        Id = id;
    }

    public BaseAttributeHolder(string type = "extra")
    {
        Type = type;
    }

    public BaseAttributeHolder()
    {

    }
}

[XmlRoot("DataSet")]
public class AddListCallHolder
{
    [XmlElement("SITE_ID")]  
    public string Site ="";  

    private BaseAttributeHolder _name = new BaseAttributeHolder(type: "");

    [XmlElement("DATA")]
    public List<BaseAttributeHolder> Attributes { get; set; }


    public AddListCallHolder()
    {
        Attributes = new List<BaseAttributeHolder>();
        Attributes.Add(new BaseAttributeHolder(id: "CLICKTHRU_URL"));
        Attributes.Add(new BaseAttributeHolder());

    }


}
```

So your AddCallHolder class will expose it's attributes as a list of attributes.

If you then serialize the above:

```
    AddListCallHolder callHolder = new AddListCallHolder();

    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AddListCallHolder));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb);

    ser.Serialize(writer, callHolder);

    sb.ToString();
```

you'll get:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <DataSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <SITE_ID />
            <Data type="extra" id="CLICKTHRU_URL" />
            <Data />
     </DataSet>
```

Which is about the only way to do it (without writing your own serialization methods which is fine but obviously more work).

EDIT:

I actually like Krizz's solution as he keeps the original properties on your class, using the array as a container for serialization, and the XmlIgnore attribute such that the serializer ignores the properties on serialization/deserialization. The properties just become array lookups/inserts on the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
[XmlRoot("DATASET")]
public class DS
{
    [XmlElement("SITE_ID")]
    public string Site ="";

    [XmlElement("DATA")]
    public Data[] Data = null;

}

[XmlRoot("DATA")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type ="";

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id = null;

    [XmlText]
    public string Text = "";
}

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DS));
var obj = xs.Deserialize(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlstring)));

MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
xs.Serialize(m,obj);
MessageBox.Show(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(m.ToArray()));
```

and here is your xmlstring

```
string xmlstring = 
    @"
<DATASET>
   <SITE_ID>123</SITE_ID>
   <DATA type=""name"">Secondary List</DATA>
   <DATA type=""extra"" id=""CLICKTHRU_URL"">http://my.domain.com/</DATA>
   <DATA type=""extra"" id=""REPLY_FORWARD_EMAIL"">support@my.domain.com</DATA>
   <DATA type=""extra"" id=""REPLY_FROM_EMAIL"">forward@my.domain.com</DATA>
   <DATA type=""extra"" id=""REPLY_FROM_NAME"">8@yahoo.com</DATA>
   <DATA type=""extra"" id=""REPLY_FORWARD_SUBJECT"">Customer Replies</DATA>
   <DATA type=""extra"" id=""HANDLE_UNSUBSCRIBE""></DATA>
   <DATA type=""extra"" id=""HANDLE_AUTOREPLY""></DATA>
   <DATA type=""extra"" id=""FOOTER_TEXT"">Confidentiality agreement…</DATA>
   <DATA type=""extra"" id=""FOOTER_HTML""> Confidentiality agreement…</DATA>
</DATASET>
";
```